# Accessing SelectList / DropDownList object in JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a 'Transaction' entry page of an ASP MVC4 project where a user can enter date, amount and tax amongst other things of a credit or debit transaction. Tax rates and types are selected from a DropDownList for example

-[EXE] 0%... Exempt

-[VAI] 20%...Standard

-[VAO] 20%... Standard

Where the three letter code in square brackets represents its type i.e. whether or not it is claimable. The DropDownList is populated with tax objects in the controller:

```
            IEnumerable<Tax> taxes = db.Taxes.ToList()
                                .Select(item => new Tax
                                     {
                                         TaxId = item.TaxId,
                                         TaxMultiplier = item.TaxMultiplier,
                                         TaxDescription = "[" + item.TaxType +"] "+ item.TaxPercentAmount + "%...." + item.TaxDescription
                                     }).AsQueryable();

        ViewBag.Taxes = new SelectList(taxes,"TaxId", "TaxDescription");
```

In the html part of the view I have

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TaxID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Taxes)
```

Finally there is also an 'AutoCalculate' flag whereby when a user checks the flag, using JQuery I make the Tax Amount field grey and uneditable and want to use the selected Tax item's 'TaxMultiplier' value to calculate the amount of VAT to be added. Previously I had put "TaxMultiplier" in place of "TaxId" in the ViewBag's SelectList (before I added different tax types for each tax rate which is crucial)

```
            $('#AutoTax').live('change', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                var total = 0;
                var amount = document.getElementById('Amount').value;
                var tax = document.getElementById('TaxId').value;         

                total = amount * tax;
                total = total.toFixed(2);

                $('#VatAmt').val(total);

            } else {
                $('#VatAmt').val(0.0);
            }
    });
```

I am really not too strong on JQuery/ JavaScript and I was wondering if anyone could help me change the above JavaScript to access the SelectList object's properties which aren't stored in the value (TaxID) or the description (TaxDescription)? Another option would be to just have a separate DropDownList for selecting the 3-Letter type code, although I want to minimise un-necessary additional fields if possible.

Comment: .live has been deprecated.  you need to change that to .on.  what isn't working about your code?

Comment: Thanks, I'll make that change, the problem is the DropDownList of taxes contains tax objects but I need to access a member of it (tax multiple) which isn't in the description or the ID (which is the 'value' selected)